# HP pavillion dv6-1355dx battery light flashing 15 mins when shut down, then won't power up until battery and power removed and plugged back in

Tags: laptop, power, battery

I have been reading about problems with the HP Pavillion dv6 series that match my problem a bit, but not exactly. I have a dv6-1355dx. It has just started refusing to power up. Here is the sequence of events:

- Shut down, all goes off
- Then the front left side battery light comes on and flashes for about 10 minutes.
- Then it goes off. All other lights are off.

After that it will not power on until I do the following:

- Unplug main power
- Take out battery, blow around in there to clean off any dust etc...,
- Shake laptop side to side gently, put battery back in, plug power back in.

Then it boots up and works normally until shut down again.

I have just replaced the battery, but that didn't seem to help. The light on the side near the power plug in comes on, so that would suggest the power source is ok.

Any suggestions as to what i should do next or is it over for my laptop :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your AC adapter. I suggest an Universal Adapter. Sometimes adapters provide the right voltage but insufficient amperage.